# Changing Environment in docker-compose up

Tags: docker-compose

I'm new to docker.

Here is my simple docker-compose file.

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  web: 
    image: 'myimage:latest'
    build: .
    ports: 
      - "5265:5265"
    environment: 
      - NODE_ENV=production
```

To run this, I usually use `docker-compose up` command.
Can I change the NODE_ENV variable to anything while running docker-compose up?

For example:

```
docker-compose up -x NODE_ENV=staging
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `docker-compose run`, you can manage services but not the complete stack. Useful for one-off commands.

```
$ docker-compose run -d -e NODE_ENV=staging web  
Ref - https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/
```

**OR**

Best way i could see as if now is to use shell & export the environment variable before doing a `docker-compose up` as below -

`$ export NODE_ENV=staging && docker-compose up -d`

Where your docker-compose will look something as below -

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  web: 
    image: 'myimage:latest'
    build: .
    ports: 
      - "5265:5265"
    environment: 
      - NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}
```